# TinyMCE removes iframe attributes width and height

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to paste a youtube iframe in to the TinyMCE Editor. Now it always removes the `width` and `height` attributes when switching from TEXT to visual. Now this is ok if values are empty, but if values exist I might need them..

I've tried with the following code in functions.php

```
function tinyMCEoptions($options) {    
    $options['extended_valid_elements'] = 'iframe[*]';
    return $options;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinyMCEoptions');
```

Which does work for all attributes but not for width and height. I've also tried

```
$options['extended_valid_elements'] = 'iframe[width|height|*]';
```

but it doesn't work. See here:

[image]

How can I make TinyMCE keep width and height for `iframe`?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me ages to figure out but here is how it works now just add below code to the functions:

```
function tinyMCEoptions($initArray) {
    $options = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $options;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $options;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinyMCEoptions');
```